# What are the rules around the re-rendering of the Apollo Query component?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I have a GraphQL field with the following definition:

```
query GetData($date: DateTime, $id: Int) {
    getData(date: $date, id: $id) {
        ...Data
    }
}
```

I have been consuming this data in React using the Apollo Client Query component, like so:

```
ids.map((id) => (
    <Query
        key={id}
        query={Queries.getData}
        variables={{
            date: date,
            id: id,
        }}
        fetchPolicy="network-only"
    >
        {({
            loading,
            error,
            data,
        }: QueryResult<{ data: any}>) => {
            return (

            );
        }}
    </Query>
```

In a separate component, I have need to reuse this data (for all ids) in the Apollo cache. For this, I wrote a local resolver

```
resolvers: {
    Query: {
        getAllData: (parent: any, args: any, cache: any) => {
            let count = 0;
            args.ids.forEach((id: number) => {
                try {
                    const cacheId = `TypeName:${id}`;

                    const locationSchedule = client.readFragment({
                        id: cacheId,
                        fragment: Fragments.Fragment,
                        fragmentName: Fragments.Fragment.definitions[0].name.value,
                    });

                    // count stuff and store in count variable
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
            return { count, __typename: 'Test' };
        },
    },
```

This is invoked from my other component like so:

```
<Query
    query={Queries.getAllData}
    variables={{
        date: date,
        ids: ids,
    }}
    //pollInterval={500}
>
    {({
        loading,
        error,
        data,
    }: QueryResult<{ getAllData: { count: number } }>) => {
        const count=
            data && data.getAllData && data.getAllData.count;

        return (
            <li className="actions__group">
                <div className="actions__item">
                    <Button
                        className={'button button--fill-green'}
                        onClick={this.onAction}
                        children={
                            count? (
                                <span className="button__badge">
                                    {count}
                                </span>
                            ) : (
                                undefined
                            )
                        }
                        disabled={count=== 0}
                    />
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }}
</Query>
```

The problem that I have is that the second Query component (the one with the `getAllData` query) does not re-render when the cache data is mutated (the first component updates fine). Everything seems to be wired up correctly (when I turn on polling the second component re-renders correctly).

What are the rules around when a Query component re-renders? I can't see why the first component re-renders when the second one does not.